# How to change the appearance of the optional argument of \cite in amsrefs?

Tags: fonts, xetex, oldstylenums, amsrefs

[Continuing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50027/5626) my [odyssey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50737/5626) with [oldstyle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51780/5626) [numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51875/5626), I'd like to disable them also in the optional (second) argument of `\cite{...}*{...}` in `amsrefs`.  Any hints how to do that?  (I'm using XeLaTeX, but this is probably irrelevant here, since the problem is now not "how to get rid of oldstyle numbers", but "how to change the style of the second `\cite`'s argument".)

**Edit:** here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsrefs}

\begin{document}

See \cite{somebook}*{p.~123}.
Also compare \citelist{\cite{somebook}\cite{anotherbook}*{p.987}}.

\begin{bibdiv}
  \begin{biblist}
    \bib{somebook}{book}{
      title={Title},
      author={Author},
      date={1999},
    }
    \bib{anotherbook}{book}{
      title={Another Title},
      author={Somebody Else},
      date={2001},
    }
  \end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

What I'd like to achieve is to change the style of "p. 123" (for instance, to boldface).

**Edit 2:** It seems that `\citelist` is a bonus challenge to this...  (I modified the MWE above to show the problem.)

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide a minimal example?

Comment: @egreg: Added, sorry for that omission.

Comment: This won't use oldstyle numerals; please tell how you get them.

Comment: Right, so assume (for the sake of simplicity and minimality of the example) that I want to have the "p. 123" in boldface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examining `amsrefs.sty`, `\citemid` is used only once:

```
\def\citemid{,\penalty9999 \space}

\def\cite@cj#1#2{%
        \leavevmode
            \begingroup
                \cite@cb#1% write info to aux file
                \ar@SK@cite#1%
                \@citeleft
                \ar@hyperlink{#1}%
                \@ifnotempty{#2}{\citemid{#2}}%
                \citeright
            \endgroup
            \ignorespaces % ignore spaces inside \citelist
        \cite@endgroup
}
```

So it seems quite safe to redefine `\citemid`:

```
\def\citemid#1{,\penalty9999 \space{\bfseries#1}}
```

Note that the text `p.~123` will be passed as `#2`, in this case.

Comment: Thanks.

The problem with oldstyle numbers is that I *do* want them *in text*, where there are *lots* of dates.  I do not want them in maths (which is obvious, and where they are absent anyway), but also in references of all kinds (where they might look strange between braces).  (Well, I like them there also, but the decision-makers don't.)

Comment: And AFAIR, `\citemid` is not really what I would like to patch here.  The problem is that `amsrefs` is *very* hard to hack imho...

Comment: Thanks again.  Works fine for `\cite`, but fails for `\citelist`...

Comment: The hack to `\citemid` seems to work. I've modified it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  You're right, this works (although I have a feeling that `\citemid` is not really for this kind of hacks).

Comment: @mbork Probably it isn't; but there seems not to be any specific formatting command for that part.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a general problem with `amsrefs`...  Is biber+biblatex better in this respect?

Comment: I'd recommend `biblatex`, sure.

Comment: I know, it's all the hotness now, but amsrefs has two important advantages: (i) one file with document and bibliography (this can be overcome of course with `\write`-ing) and (ii) one binary to compile ((pdf|xe|)latex) (which seems much more difficult to overcome, maybe by means of `\write18`?).  And my question remains: is changing the style of citations (and "biblists") easier in biblatex?